# -define and -limit in Im4java

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick, im4java

I need to know how to translate a imagemagick commandline-command into java im4java code
commandline:

```
convert -limit memory 40GiB -define registry:temporary-path=F:\\imageMagick Row_1.png Row_2.png -append Row_12.png"
```

I know how to use convert and -append in im4java but what about -define and -limit? Here is what I got:

```
    IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
    op.addImage("Row_1.png","Row_2.png");
    op.appendVertically();
    op.addImage("Row_12.png");                      
    cmd.run(op);
```

maybe just add `op.limit("memory 40GiB")` and `op.define("registry:temporary-path=F:\\imageMagick")` ? I don't know whether it is the same..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The op.limit() is buggy and I had to use `addRawArgs("-limit","memory","20GiB")` instead of `op.limit("memory 40GiB")`
source: http://sourceforge.net/p/jmagick/mailman/message/33285563/

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  To view the actual command you will be generating put this line of code in before cmd.run(op)

```
System.out.println(op.toString());
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I asked in the mailing list and op.limit is buggy. See here: http://sourceforge.net/p/jmagick/mailman/message/33285563/